# startTLS in apache mina without clientside authentication

Tags: java, ssl, handshake, apache-mina, starttls

I am trying to implement startTLS in apache Mina taking following reference.
http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/apidocs/org/apache/mina/filter/ssl/SslFilter.html

My code is as follows:

@Override
 public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {

jsonparser(msg);

```
if (condition) {
   startTLS();
```

}

}

SslFilter sslFilter;
public void startTLS() {

```
try {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");               
    sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());       

    sslFilter = new SslFilter(sslContext);
    sslFilter.setUseClientMode(true);
    sslFilter.setNeedClientAuth(false);
    session.getFilterChain().addFirst("mySSL", sslFilter);       
    session.setAttribute(SslFilter.DISABLE_ENCRYPTION_ONCE, Boolean.TRUE);
    assert session.getAttribute(SslFilter.DISABLE_ENCRYPTION_ONCE) == null;
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStactTrace();
```

}

}

I am trying to put things using JSON. So every message I received I am parsing with JSON library.
Negotiation message is : SESSION_UNSECURED
Track trace is as follows:

```
02-05 12:50:20.365: W/System.err(994): Unexpected character (S) at position 0.
02-05 12:50:20.374: W/System.err(994):     at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
02-05 12:50:20.394: W/System.err(994):     at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
02-05 12:50:20.394: W/System.err(994):     at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
02-05 12:50:20.404: W/System.err(994):     at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
02-05 12:50:20.444: W/System.err(994):     at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
02-05 12:50:20.444: W/System.err(994):     at network.com.parse(com.java:146)
02-05 12:50:20.444: W/System.err(994):     at network.com.messageReceived(com.java:106)
02-05 12:50:20.474: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:690)
02-05 12:50:20.474: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
02-05 12:50:20.474: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
02-05 12:50:20.474: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
02-05 12:50:20.487: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:214)
02-05 12:50:20.494: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
02-05 12:50:20.494: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
02-05 12:50:20.514: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
02-05 12:50:20.514: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.flushScheduledEvents(SslHandler.java:322)
02-05 12:50:20.524: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:497)
02-05 12:50:20.524: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
02-05 12:50:20.524: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
02-05 12:50:20.524: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
02-05 12:50:20.556: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:109)
02-05 12:50:20.564: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
02-05 12:50:20.564: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:410)
02-05 12:50:20.574: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:710)
02-05 12:50:20.574: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:664)
02-05 12:50:20.604: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:653)
02-05 12:50:20.604: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67)
02-05 12:50:20.604: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1124)
02-05 12:50:20.614: W/System.err(994):     at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
02-05 12:50:20.614: W/System.err(994):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-05 12:50:20.614: W/System.err(994):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-05 12:50:20.625: W/System.err(994):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

finally it works. Implementation is as follows.

```
public void startTLS() {

    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsa) {
        System.out.println("Exception : No Such Algorithm");
    } catch(KeyManagementException kme) {
        System.out.println("Exception : KeyManagementException:");
    }//try-catch


    IoFilterChain chain = session.getFilterChain();
    SslFilter sslFilter = (SslFilter) chain.get("sslFilter");

    if (sslFilter == null) {
        sslFilter = new SslFilter(sslContext);
        sslFilter.setUseClientMode(true);
        if ((cipherSuites != null) && !cipherSuites.isEmpty()) {
            sslFilter.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites.toArray( new String[cipherSuites.size()] )); 
        } 

        chain.addFirst("sslFilter", sslFilter);

    }else {
        try {
            sslFilter.startSsl(this.session);
        } catch(SSLException se) {
            System.out.println("SslException:"+se);
        }
    }//if-else

}//startTLS
```

If any mistakes I am doing pls let me know.

Thanks Emmanuel Lécharny for guiding.